# Remove leading zero from jclock

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

Anyone ever used [jclock](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jclock) and know how to remove the leading zero for the 12h setting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no direct way of doing this with jclock because it displays the time as per the format properties passed to it.

If you are comfortable changing the jclock code you can change the lines like this one

```
  case "M": // minute as a decimal number
          return ((dateObject.getMinutes() 

to


  case "M": // minute as a decimal number
          return dateObject.getMinutes();
```

I'd advise you may be add you own format property, using a suitable name like "X" and return it without the leading zeros or whatever changes you prefer